# Bind AngularJS Value to Zurb Foundation Slider

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I need assistance binding AngularJS values to Zurb Foundation elements. I have a slider and a input box that displays the value of the slider next to it and I want to be able to update that value with AngularJS but adding any Angular code into the elements properties renders the slider inoperable. If I enter {{attrib}} into data-end, it will break the slider.

```
<div id="VideoContainer" ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
<div id = 'Controls' ng-controller="SettingsControlsController as setCtrl">
    <div class="slider" data-slider data-initial-start="2" data-end="8">
      <span class="slider-handle"  data-slider-handle role="slider" tabindex="1" aria-controls="numVideos"></span>
      <span class="slider-fill" data-slider-fill></span>
    </div>
    <input type = "number" id="numVideos" />
</div>
```

Comment: You are using the Controller as syntax here, and have two controllers.  Which controller is `attrib` a property of?  Have you tried `{{mainCtrl.attrib}}` or `{{setCtrl.attrib}}` (as appropriate)?

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes I have tried {{setCtrl.attrib}} and it will display the correct value but when implemented inside Foundation Slider elements, they break the slider. I can't even attach a ng-change to the input because it breaks angular. Obviously there is a conflict between the foundation js code that runs the slider and angular.